# Parameter not reaching controller on server but in local eclipse setup

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, spring-4

I have the following two webservices defined in my controller (`update_name` and `update_definition`). I am testing these two webservices
 on my local eclipse setup and then deploying it on RHEL OS. Both the webservices works fine on local eclipse setup when I used the following URLs
 for local testing

For `update_name`

```
 http://localhost:8080/MyProject/update_name?id=1234&name=localNameTest
  http://localhost:8080/MyProject/update_definition?id=1234&definition=localdefinitionTest
```

I can see the following JSON response for the above two webservice calls respectively:

```
 {
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "message" : "Updated Name!"
}

{
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "message" : "Updated Definition Name!"
}
```

However, when I try to run the same two webservices on my server, for some reason the `name` parameter isn't reaching the 
controller for `update_name` webservice and I end up getting the following error all time :

```
{
  "status" : "ERROR",
  "message" : "Invalid Name Parameter"
}
```

I see `New Name` value in the log as empty for this line `logger.info("update__name ws params :ID " +id+" New  Name:"+name);` where 
as it shows up in my local setup eclipse console logs

On the other hand,on the server, the webservice `update_definition` works perfectly fine as it works on local eclipse setup and I get the same success 
message as I get in local :

```
{
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "message" : "Updated Definition Name!"
}
```

Does anyone know what wrong I could be doing? I can't figure out as things are working perfectly fine in my local exlipse setup. 
On the server, I have even did `mvn clean` on the project and then built it but it didn't help.

Controller for webservice `update_name`:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update_name", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateName
    (
     @RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "0") Integer id,
     @RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "") String name

    ) {

  String wsStatusJsonString = null;
  logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
  logger.info("update__name ws params :ID " + id + " New  Name:" + name);
  boolean updateStatus = true;

  try {

   // Validate the input parameters.
   if (id < 1) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid ID parameter");
   }
   if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(name)) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid  Name Parameter");
   }
   EmployeeDao employeeDao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("employeeDao");
   Company company = null;
   List < Company > companyList = employeeDao.findByEmployeeId(id);

   if ((companyList != null) && (!companyList.isEmpty())) {
    company = companyList.get(0);
    company.setName(name);
    updateStatus = employeeDao.insertOrUpdate(company);
    logger.info("update__name:" + updateStatus);
    if (updateStatus) {
     wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(true, "Updated  Name!", true);
    } else {
     wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(false, "Unable to update  Name!", true);
    }

   }

  } catch (Throwable th) {
   th.printStackTrace();
   wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(false, th.getMessage(), true);
  }

  return wsStatusJsonString;
 }
```

Controller for webservice `update_definition`:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/update_definition", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String updateDefinition
  (
   @RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "0") Integer id,
   @RequestParam(value = "definition", defaultValue = "") String definition

  ) {

   String wsStatusJsonString = null;
   logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   logger.info("update__definition ws params :ID " + id + " New  Name:" + definition);
   boolean updateStatus = true;
   try {
    // Validate the input parameters.
    if (id < 1) {
     throw new Exception("Invalid ID parameter");
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(definition)) {
     throw new Exception("Invalid  Definition Parameter");
    }
    EmployeeDao employeeDao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("employeeDao");
    Company company = null;
    List < Company > companyList = employeeDao.findByEmployeeId(id);

    if ((companyList != null) && (!companyList.isEmpty())) {
     company = companyList.get(0);
     company.setDefinition(definition);
     updateStatus = employeeDao.insertOrUpdate(company);
     logger.info("update__definition:" + updateStatus);
     if (updateStatus) {
      wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(true, "Updated Definition Name!", true);
     } else {
      wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(false, "Unable to update Definition Name!", true);
     }

    }

   } catch (Throwable th) {
    th.printStackTrace();
    wsStatusJsonString = GenericOrmStatusView.OrmStatusToJsonString(false, th.getMessage(), true);
   }

   return wsStatusJsonString;
  }
```

Comment: Just for testing, have you tried changing the "name" request parameter to something else (ex. "definition")? Does it work with a different parameter name? What servlet container are you using on your RHEL server?

Comment: I haven't tried that. Will test it tomorrow. By the way, does that "name" has anything to do with anything else Or can it be anything? I am using Tomcat on RHEL server. And I used Tomcat on my local Eclipse setup as well.

Comment: I think "name" should case no problem, but there is nothing obvious in your code, that could cause such issue. So it could be a first step to debug.

Comment: Hmm, it's kind of confusing why it works perfectly fine on my local eclipse setup but on the server. I have written many other webservices without any problem which worked fine on both setup except this one. Anyways, I will test that thing and comment here after testing.

Comment: I tested by changing `name` to `testName` and it didn't work.

Comment: How are you sending a request? Are you using Curl? If not, try using it, to avoid browsers doing something "clever".

Comment: I am using POSTMAN client for sending a request. Not testing on the browser.

Comment: Ok. Have you checked the access-log, do you still see the parameter there? Also try to inject `HttpServletRequest` to get the URI information from it, you should be just able to define it in the controller as a param, and it will get injected. And log useful values such as `getQueryString()`, and `getParameter("name")`

Comment: I actually tried changing `@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "") String name` to this `@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "Default Value") String name` and I noticed the `Default Value` was getting inserted without error even after supplying `name` parameter.  I didn't quite understand how to inject `HttpServletRequest`.Please elaborate. thanks

Comment: Just add `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter to your `updateName` method, Spring will take care of injecting it. In the methodBody add something like this (in Java 8 printing all request params): `request.getParameterMap().entrySet().forEach(entry -> logger.info("Parameter: " + entry.getKey() + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue())));
` to log out the parameters the servlet container (Tomcat) sees. This should answer whether the problem is the integration with the servlet, or you parameter don't correctly make it your server.

Comment: Hey @helospark , So I did as you mentioned and here is what I obtained:
When I ran the webservice on the server with the parameters `id = 1234` and `name = Server Test`, I noticed in the console that these 
two parameters printed as follows :  `Parameter: id[1234]` and on the next line ` Parameter: name[Server Test]`

But the strange thing is,just like before,this line still doesn't show `Server Test` printing on the console and it only shows the `id`:
`logger.info("update__name ws params :ID " +id+" New  Name:"+name);` which I am not able to understand.

Comment: Very strange. I cannot reproduce it using standalone Tomcat 8 based on the code you posted. I see no reason why it shouldn't work. Have you tried local standalone Tomcat? Also is there no weird UTF8 characters in the "name" param (ex. zero width space :smile: ) Could you post a full minimal example program (ex. as a Github repo containing a fully stripped project, that contains just logging + everything else to register it that shows the error on Tomcat) and a Curl request (I trust it more than Postman). A Tomcat version could also be useful and then I will try on Linux Tomcat to reproduce.

Comment: @helospark I updated the name of webservice from `update_name` to something else and finally it started working on the RHEL server. Not sure what was the reason before. Thanks for all your support and willingness to help me further. Appreciated.